# How to write a general db insert function in php

Tags: php, mysql

This question is kind of two-fold - a) am I approaching it in a valid way, and b) how would it be done in php.

I have hundreds of php forms in a legacy site, going forward I am trying to clean up the code and modularise it more.

So I am creating a database functions file, in which I would like to use a general INSERT function.
Now, each form will have a totally different table, therefore different fields to insert.

I cannot find the best way to write this function - I was thinking something like this:

```
function insert_form_data($table, $arr_fields, $arr_values)
```

In this way, I am unsure how to structure the myqli query function to use the fields and values array when they are unknown.

So is this a valid way to do it, if so, please help with the syntax. Or should I spend the extra time now refactoring everything into using the mvc structure, in which case each table/form would be a 'model' etc..

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple example for what you want is

```
public function insert_form_data($table, $arr_fields, $arr_values)
{

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(", ", $arr_fields).') VALUES ('.implode(", ",  $arr_values).')';

    return mysql_query($sql);

}
```

you can change it accordingly if you are using PDO connection. Better if you make complete class which check connection on constructor and perform all insert update delete function.

Comment: Maybe don't show the `mysql_query()` function. You'll get ridiculed very quickly because it's a deprecated library. (`PDO` or `mysqli` are the way to go here)

Comment: I just want to show how things can be done and this is just for demonstration. that's why I mentioned to use PDO

Comment: In a production environment, it is very important that $table, $arr_fields, and $arr_values be sanitized/error-checked before the query is generated and run.  If these values came from user input then the example implementation would be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

Method Implementation

```
public function addData($_tableName, $_dataString){
    $qr_string = 'INSERT INTO `'.$_tableName.'` SET '.$_dataString;
    $this->_message = ($this->res = $this->mysqli->query($qr_string)) ? 'Success' : $this->mysqli->error ;
    return $this->_message;
}
```

Hope This Helps